# Sum of squares number theory question

Tags: number-theory

I've been stuck on this for the past few days. Some insight would be greatly appreciated

Let $p_n=a_n^2+b_n^2 ,n=1,2,3,...$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive integers. Prove that for every positive integer $M$, we can always find positive integers $A$ and $B$ such that $p_1p_2...p_m=A^2+B^2$

Comment: Consider $(a_1+ib_1)(2_2+ib_2)\cdots(a_m+ib_m)$.

Comment: See [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

Comment: Thanks a lot! ds

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use induction on $m$. Everything relies on this light version of *Lagrange's identity*:
$$(x^2+y^2)(x'^2+y'^2)-(xx'+yy')^2=(xy'-x'y)^2.$$

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be proven by induction on $m \ge 1$. Base case $m = 1$ is true since you are given that $p_1 = a_1^2 + b_1^2$, thus you can take $A = a_1, B = b_1$. Assume it is true for $m = k$, that is: $p_1p_2\cdots p_k = A^2 + B^2$, then $p_1p_2\cdots p_{k+1} = (A^2+B^2)(a_{k+1}^2 + b_{k+1}^2) = (Aa_{k+1} - Bb_{k+1})^2 + (Ab_{k+1} + Ba_{k+1})^2= C^2+D^2$. Thus it is true for $m = k+1$ and therefore is true for all $m \ge 1$.